# Increment 0.3 in Awk

Tags: awk, printf

I would like to print the range of numbers from -0.6 to +6.9 with the increments of 0.3:

```
-0.6
-0.3 
0.0 
0.3
...
6.9
```

I know that it can be done, e.g., for the range of numbers from 1 to 7 with the increments of 1 in the following way:

```
for ((run=1;run<8;run++))
do
printf "%s " $num
done
```

But the same idea does not work here (also, I guess run++0.3 is incorrect):

```
for ((run=-0.3;run<7.2;run++0.3))
do
printf "%s " $num
done
```

Comment: That looks like shell syntax, not awk.

Comment: `awk` doesn't use `(( .... ))`, only `( .... )` and code blocks are delmited with `{ .... }` instead of `do ... done`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that your sample code is in shell syntax (probably bash), not awk. bash doesn't do floating-point arithmetic, at least not directly.

Your first loop, in awk, would look like this:

```
for (run = 1; run < 8; run ++) {
    print run
}
```

The obvious (but potentially incorrect) way to do your second loop, again using awk syntax, would be:

```
for (run = 0.3; run <= 7.2; run += 0.3) {
    print run
}
```

(Your question has been edited once or twice, and I'm not sure what upper bound you want; I'll assume `<= 7.2` is what you're looking for.)

But that might omit the final `7.2` because of floating-point rounding errors. (It happens to work on my system, but I wouldn't count on it. Neither `0.3` nor `7.2` can be represented exactly in binary floating-point.)

You can reliably cover the full range by using an integer to iterate over the range, then dividing by 10:

```
for (run = 3; run <= 72; run += 3) {
    print run / 10
}
```

To turns this into a self-contained executable script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    for (run = 3; run <= 72; run += 3) {
        print run / 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to handle some more floating point numbers you can also think about bc.

To include a bc statement inline in a shell script pipe it into bc - e.g.

```
echo 'for ( a=-0.6; a<=6.9; a=a+0.3) { print a,"\n"; }' | bc
```